# What happens when I pick up the Black Candle when I have Curse of the Labyrinth?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

The *Black Candle* removes every curse on pickup.

For example when I have Curse of the Blind and I pick it up the question marks dissappear and become items again.

But what does that mean for Curse of the Labyrinth does half the floor disappear or just one extra item room?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/bindingofisaac/comments/2n27xl/black_candle_labyrinth/):

> I bought it on an XL floor. Nothing happens. The floor is already generated, it doesn't change after that. Future floors won't be cursed though. I'm pretty sure it's the only curse that isn't instantly mitigated.